# Cannot see result using return

Tags: python

Why can I not see the result of `jump()`?

```
from random import randint

def jump():
    return randint(1, 6)

jump()
```

Why do I have to use `print` instead of `return` to see the result?

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It in fact returns a value. You can print it with `print(jump())`

Comment: because `print()` prints and `return` returns as the names suggest

Comment: What is the "working" alternative here?

Comment: Printing to stdout itself is pretty expensive and I'd prefer both a) not to see the garbage it throws into the terminal and b) not incur that overhead at all. `print` is unnecessary when you want to just calculate the result of the function and use that value elsewhere, there's no need to see the value unless you explicitly call `print()`

Answer (score 10):

If you want any output from the code, then you need to use `print`, as `return` only returns the value to the caller.

```
print(jump())
```

In python shell, however, you can see the returning value of a function without printing.

```
>>> from random import randint
>>>
>>> def jump():
...     return randint(1, 6)
...
>>> jump()
5
>>>
```

Comment: The confusion seems to be about the difference between a script and the python console, as you observed. This might be more helpful to others with the same misunderstanding if you said something like, "In normal use in a script" and perhaps gave an example of j = jump() and just use it, or print it also as a trace of the program.

Answer (score -1):

Your function returns a value, with nowhere to display it. Your options include:

```
from random import randint

def jump():
    return randint(1, 6)

print(jump())
```

or

```
from random import randint

def jump():
    return randint(1, 6)

test = jump()

print(test)
```

Comment: they have the additional option of printing within the method definition, i.e. `print randint(1,6)` if printing to the console is the only desired behavior